# How to declare Java List of Object where each one implements Comparable

Tags: java, generics

Here is the situation...

I have a `List<Object>` where I have to pass it around into fairly generic parts of my code. In some parts, the list needs to be sorted.

I will NOT know upfront what type of object is in the list. However, by how this list is used, I am guaranteed that the contract of `Comparable` such that each item in the list is of the same type and is able to be compared to each other.

In other words, in some cases, the real type will end up being `String`, in other cases, `Date`. In yet other cases, something `Custom` that `implements Comparable<Custom>`.

However, in *every* case, if the real type is `String`, **all** of the items in the list will be of type `String`.

Let me be more specific to improve this question a bit...

Here is a class I am working on:

```
public class Thing {
   private Map<String, List<SourcedValue<Object>>> properties;
}
```

Then, `SourcedValue` is this:

```
public class SourcedValue<T> {
  private T value;
  private List<Sources> sources;
}
```

So, how do you suggest I declare this?

Comment: Don't pass a `List<Object>`; use make it generic to some type `T` which is `Comparable`. Like, `public static <T> void doSomething(List<? super Comparable<T>> al)`

Comment: @ElliottFrisch wouldn't it be `<? extends Comparable<T>>`?

Comment: @BenjaminUrquhart Depends. Producer extends, consumer super (PECS).

Comment: @BenjaminUrquhart Regarding PECS, see [*What is PECS (Producer Extends Consumer Super)?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2723397/642706)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need all of the elements of the list to be `Comparable`, but not just `Comparable`, comparable to each other.  The way to enforce this at a method level is to declare a type variable with a bound of `Comparable` to itself.  Because a `Comparable` acts as a consumer, [PECS (producer extends, consumer super)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/what-is-pecs-producer-extends-consumer-super) suggests to have a lower bound on the type argument of `Comparable` itself.

```
public <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void yourMethod(List<T> list) {
     // Your implementation here.
}
```

Depending on your exact situation, the type variable `T` may be on a class instead of a method.

```
public class YourClass<T extends Comparable<? super T>> {
    public void yourMethod(List<T> list) {
         // Your implementation here.
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! (and yikes! I forgot how fun generics are. :-) ) Can you please edit your response, adding the edit/addition I made to the original question? This definitely looks like the right answer though for the methods/classes.

Comment: It's unclear how your original example pertains to your added example.

Comment: I think I got it. Thanks! I have a followup which I will link here after I post it.

Comment: My followup questions is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56498727/how-to-declare-java-comparable-in-this-situation